# hair particles disappear when joining objects

Tags: modifiers

I'm making an eyebrow and, with the mesh selected, I have added hair particles with some settings. I have the eye below that. I want it to match with the eye on other side, so I clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join. It joined and I got the other eyebrow, but the hair particles disappeared. May i know the reason why it disappeared and how to recover it?

[image]

[image]

**After adding vertex group in density same result**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Joining the meshes is making the Particle modifier disappear.

When you join two meshes the active object modifiers are preserved. The active object is the last one you selected, and will be outlined in a lighter orange. In your case you're selecting the eye last, and its modifiers are being preserved, not the eyebrow's ones.

You need to select the eyebrow mesh last, then join.

Also, to avoid hair getting scattered everywhere when you join the meshes do the following before joining:

1. Select the eyebrow, go into Edit mode.
2. Select the area that should have hair.
3. In the Object Data panel, create a new Vertex Group, rename it to your liking and click on "Assign".
4. In the Particle panel, scroll down to the Vertex Groups and set the vertex group you created as *Density*.
5. Now you can leave edit mode and join the meshes.

[image: Step-by-step GIF]

Comment: Its still the same i have attach the vertex density file plz check above in question. Eye brow file also attached

Comment: @ateks As I stated in my answer you **must** select the mesh with the hair modifier **last**. You're selecting the eye last. It must be the eyebrow. If you don't, it won't work. 

Unrelated: Your second eye (Sphere.001) has normal issues. After joining the meshes you'll need to go into edit mode and recalculate normals.